# How to Execute child projects using 1 Jar in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

So, I have a Parent Maven Project consisting of two Child Maven Projects.
I have a main function in Project-1 and other in Project-2 I want to execute both `Project-1.main()` and `Project-2.main()` simultaneously using 1 Jar File how do I do that?

```
ParentProject
pom.xml
----Project-1
    ----pom.xml
    ----src
        ----main
            ----com.name.example
                   ---- Main-1.java

----Project-2   
    ----pom.xml 
    ----src
        ----main
            ----com.name.example
                   ---- Main-2.java
```

Answer (score 1):

With this design, you should get two jars, one for each project. You can then run both the jars.

If you want a single jar, have a single project instead of two and run the Main classes using:-

```
java -cp /path/to/jar/myJar.jar com.name.example.Main1
java -cp /path/to/jar/myJar.jar com.name.example.Main2
```

Comment: @khmarbaise i want to open the Main2 using Main1 as a thread.